# Summation using binomial theorem

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Find the sum $$\sum_{x=1}^{m} \Big(\frac{2^x-1}{2^x}\Big)^n$$ where $n$ belongs to natural number.

Comment: Is anything known about $m$ and $n$ aside from them being natural numbers?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins No Sir.

Comment: It does not appear obvious that there is a simple closed-form function corresponding to the above sum. Why do you believe that the above sum can be found?